# compare output between sqlite and list

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, sqlite, tuples

The problem is when i want to compare to list from sqlite and a list

```
date_in=("25/08/2018")
date_modified=datetime.strptime(date_in, "%d/%m/%Y")
date=date_modified.date()

consulta.execute("SELECT hora FROM citas WHERE fecha=(?)",(date,))

schedule_appointments1 = consulta.fetchall()

schedule_appointments=list(schedule_appointments1)

schedule=["10:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","12:30"]

for x in schedule_appointments:
    for y in schedule:
        if x==y:
            print("ok")
            schedule.remove(x)
```

when I run, nothing happend, so "x" not equal "y" 
if I print one bye one

```
for x in schedule_appointments:
    for y in schedule:
        print("x= ", x, type(x))
        print("y= ",y, type(y))
        if x==y:
            print("ok")
```

the result if

```
x=  ('12:00',) class 'tuple'
y=  11:00 class 'str'
x=  ('11:00',) class 'tuple'
y=  11:00 class 'str'
```

I see one is tuple and other is str but

`schedule_appointments=list(schedule_appointments1)` is a list and `schedule=["11:00"]` is a list so I dont understand,

I need that happened

```
if x==y:
    print("ok")
```

in resumen I want of the one list remove what the database gives me

and other petition, can I do that why numpy? how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an additional list comprehension before running your loop:

schedule_appointments = [item[0] for item in schedule_appointments]

Because you get from sqlite3 a list of tuples (each one with a single element). As shown when you log both x and y. You don’t get a list of single elements.

Comment: Ok thank.. i gona try that.. and i can use numpy y this action?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t use numpy application personally but my suggestion is a pure python way of working. It should work therefore with numpy as with any external python package.
In other words: list comprehension don’t depend on a specific package.

Comment: ok thanks really.can u help me in other problems? is herer --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030862/checkbox-in-bucle-for-python-3-7